# Mirrors reflecting heroes' images in the mirrors. It was as if they were trapped in another dimension

Tags: story-identification, books

I sometimes think about this book that I read sometime in the late 1980s. It was a story about four or five teenagers / young adults who traveled between dimensions, although I seem to remember that this was involuntary, at least at first.

The most striking memory I have of this book is the cover. The cover was mostly blue, showing  mirrors at varying angles to each other with the heroes of the book reflecting their images in the mirrors. It was as if they were trapped in another dimension and could see where they wanted to go but could not get there. It seems to me that this imagery was more or less depicting the plot line.

I would be thrilled to find this book again, even if I find that that it seems a little childlike to me now. Any help appreciated.